# Automatically update Dataframe whenever object attributes change

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a person class:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, score):
        self.name=name
        self.score=score
    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            'name':self.name,
            'score':self.score,
        }
```

and I'm making a few Person objects and adding them to an array:

```
a=Person("Sam", 2)
b=Person("Tim", 3)
people=[a,b]
```

Now making a dataframe out of that array using the *to_dict* method

```
df=pd.DataFrame.from_records([s.to_dict() for s in people])
```

I would like to have this dataframe synchronized with the objects, so that whenever there is a score change, it gets instantly updated.

Comment: Could you store your `Person` objects in the `DataFrame`? This may allow your attributes to be synced, depending on whether `pandas` makes a copy(?)

Comment: Yes @dspencer, that would be great. As far as I know you can only store static fields in the dataframe. I guess I'll write the function to update the df and call it each time there is the possibility for a value change.

Comment: From my quick test, the attributes will propagate back to the DataFrame, will post example in a moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store the `Person` objects themselves in the `DataFrames` and update the same instances of the class, then the attribute changes will propagate back to the `DataFrame` as per this example:

```py
person1 = Person("Daniel", 95)                                                  

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"People": [person1]})                              
print(df.People.iloc[0].score) # prints 95                                              

person1.score = 90                                                              
print(df.People.iloc[0].score) # prints 90
```

Comment: Do you know how I can get the object fields in separate columns of the df (with the updated values)?

Comment: Only way I can suggest would be to make each of those attributes a class themselves, even if each class only stores a single variable. I would suggest that it would be best to convert the format of the DataFrame when you want to use it, rather than implement something a little "hacky" like this.

Comment: I decided to call this and recreate the df everytime there's a value change. It's not very efficient but I'll do for this scale. 
df=pd.DataFrame.from_records([s.to_dict() for s in people])

Comment: How often do you need the DataFrame? It's not necessarily the best storage solution for your data, depends on the usage

Comment: I'm just using it for monitoring purposes during development. The actual data that the app is working with are the object fields

Comment: In that case, there's no major issue with having to reconstruct the `DataFrame`. I wouldn't make substantial changes to production code for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly make a container, which stores your dataframe and allows you to make changes to each `Person` while updating your dataframe.

```
class People:
    def __init__(self, *person):        
        for p in person:
            setattr(self, p.name, p.score)

    @property
    def df(self):
        return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(self.__dict__, orient='index', columns=['score'])
```

For example

```
people = People(Person('Bob', 2), Person('Carl', 5))
people.df

#       score
# Bob       2
# Carl      5
```

Then you can change an attribute

```
people.Carl = 10
people.df

#       score
# Bob       2
# Carl     10
```

You can also add a new `Person`

```
people.james = 5
people.df

#       score
# Bob       2
# Carl     10
# james     5
```